# Mongoose.js schema options for embedded documents are not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am very new to node.js and mongoose. I have schema as follows.

```
var sub = Schema({"title": {type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true},
                  "uniqueId": Schema.ObjectId}

var main = Schema({"name": {type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true, dropDups: true},
                  "subs": [sub]}
```

This is working. Documents are inserted. Subs are getting added. Problems are as follows.

What I was expecting here is when I add new sub into main. It will check the title is present or not and throw exception if not. It will check if title is unique or not. Also, it will assign the object id to uniqueId field on its own. But this is not happening. It is not checking if title is present and unique. Also, objectId is not getting assigned to uniqueId, it is assigned to _id instead.

Here is the code for adding the sub into main.

```
MainModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
        request["_id"], 
        {$push: {subs: {"title": "New title"}}}, {}, function(err, doc) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(doc);
        }
    );
```

Mongoose logs this query as.

```
MainModel.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("537caa880519db710d7b5b2a") }) [] { '$push': { subs: { _id: ObjectId("537d6b96f927d6573c6e1044"),  title: 'New title' } } } { upsert: false, new: true }
```

If you see ObjectId is getting assigned to _id and not uniqueId. Also, it does not check if title is present and is unique.

May be there is silly mistake on my side. What am I missing here.

Answer (score 2):

Defaults, setters, validators and middleware are not applied when any findAndModify helper is used. See here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So, only solution is to find, change the document and save the document? Is there any better solution? Because, I will have to first retrieve, then iterate over the array, change the array element and then update document.

Comment: It depends, sometimes it is better( fx from performance point of view) to ensure consistency in code